# .map() img src attribute undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so I want to .map() the src values of the html content of #stage to the variable srcArray

```
var content = $('#stage').html();
var srcArray = $.map($(content), function(el) {
return {value: $(el).children().attr('src')};
});
```

but when I console.log the array, each src value comes up as undefined. Anyone know what's up?

html is

```
<div id="stage">
<div style="left:xxx, top:xxx">
<img src="xxxxx" style="width:xxx, height:xxx"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Do I need to convert the src value to a string to have it show up on the chrome console?

Comment: I don't think that is enough... edit the question with the html for  `#stage` element

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kf5xmr7t/1/

Comment: I should have mentioned, the src value needs to print as a string

Comment: sorry what did you mean.. can you give a sample output

Comment: do you mean like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kf5xmr7t/2/

Comment: so it would log the url of the image, rather than the image as an element

Comment: so I'd see xxxxx in the result box

Comment: I see the broken link icon still

Comment: ripped page icon .... no still coming up as undefined

Comment: can you try to recreate the issue in the fiddle... (whether the fiddle is showing the expected output?)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Harleymckee/qb1h17ga/  I want it to show "htt.p://9pixs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/dog-pics_1404159465.jpg" instead of the dog

Comment: So I can store the url in another variable as a string

Comment: sorry your fiddle is the same as mine.... did you make any changes to it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well the issue is with your children() selection and reading the attribute. It will read the attribute of the first child. So if the first child does not have the attribute it will be undefined. So you need to actually select the element you want. It is also weird you are selecting the html and than building a nodeset based on that html. Just do the selection and use map

```
var srcArray = $('#stage [src]').map(
     function () {
         return { value: $(this).attr('src')};
     }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get all the `img` from the `#stage` element.

```
var srcArray = $('#stage').find('img').map(function() {
  return { value: $(this).attr('src') };
}).get();
```

Comment: @epascarello Yep, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :**

**1.** statement `return {value: $(el).children().attr('src')};`  Will execute for each children of  `'div#stage'` but stage also have a
    `div` which doesn't have any `src` attribute.

**2.** In case 'div#stage'`have multiple`img` elements then above statement will return only one result

**3.** Statement `$(content)` creating new html elements .Never create new content if you just want to treverse (A bad practice).

**Solution :**

**1.** Filter children so that only `img` tag will be selected.

**2.** Map on `children('img')` so that if there are more than 1 `img` element,code will be executed for each `img`

**3.** Use `$('#stage')` instead of `$(content)` (which is creating new html elements)

**Try this-**

```
var content = $('#stage').html();
var srcArray = $.map($(content).children("img"), function (el) {//better way use $.map($('#stage').children("img"), function (el) {
    return {
        value: $(el).attr('src')
    };
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(srcArray))
```

**Update:-**

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/kf5xmr7t/3/)

Comment: Why should the OP try this? Please explain the problem with the OP's code and why your suggestion solves it.